# Trigger to check for duplicates and update a value of an attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, for-loop, each

I have one table that has a code and and index attributes.

I'm trying to create a trigger that will check the values of code. If there is a duplicate in the inserted code, the index will be triggered to increase by 1. Example:

```
code|c_index
111 | 1
112 | 1
113 | 1
111 | 2
114 | 1
112 | 2
111 | 3
```

This is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
create trigger trg_update
after insert on trial

for each row

declare v_index;

begin

select max(nvl(trial.c_index, 0)) into v_index
from trial;

if new.code = code then
set new.c_index = v_index

else 
set new.c_index = 1

end if;
end;
```

...............................

I've tryed to do a new better one, but still not working:

```
create trigger trg_update
after insert on trial
for each row
declare v_index number;

begin

if :new.code = :old.code then
select max(nvl(c_index, 0)) into v_index
from trial
where code = :new.code;

set :new.c_index = v_index + 1

else 
set :new.c_index = 1

end if;
end;
```

What's the problem with the codes above and what is the solution for the problem?

...............................................

UPDATE:

After running this code:

```
create trigger trg_update
AFTER insert on trial
for each ROW

DECLARE v_index NUMBER := -1; -- "-1" is put in place so to be below the minimum value of the column
DECLARE v_cnt NUMBER   := 0;

BEGIN

SELECT MAX(c_index), COUNT(*)
  INTO :v_index, v_cnt
  FROM trial
 WHERE code = :new.code;

IF v_index <> -1 AND v_cnt > 1 THEN
--Only one update here, for the newly inserted row explicitly
  UPDATE trial
     SET c_index = c_index +1
   WHERE code    = :new.code
     AND c_index = v_index
     AND ROWNUM  = 1;

END IF;
END;
```

Some problems displayed:

1- Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" 
2- Error(7,8): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'V_INDEX' 
3- Error(9,15): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CODE'

This is the new code after trying to fix errors number 2 and 3:

```
create or replace trigger trg_update
AFTER insert on trial
for each ROW

declare vindex NUMBER := -1; -- "-1" is put in place so to be below the minimum value of the column
declare vcnt NUMBER   := 0;

BEGIN

SELECT MAX(c_index), COUNT(*)
  INTO vindex, vcnt
  FROM trial
 WHERE code = :new.code;

IF vindex <> -1 AND vcnt > 1 THEN
--Only one update here, for the newly inserted row explicitly
  UPDATE trial
     SET c_index = c_index +1
   WHERE code    = :new.code AND c_index = vindex AND ROWNUM  = 1;

END IF;

END;
```

However, the first error still displays.

Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

In addition to this error:

Error(19,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

How can I solve these errors??

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You will find using triggers in this way will be painful on many levels. It's tempting at first and *seems* like a good idea, but it's not.

Triggers were invented before DRI was standardized. Their purpose is to enforce referential integrity. If you use DRI whenever feasible and triggers only for RI otherwise, you'll get along much better with your DBMS.

To do what you want, change your `insert` to use a correlated subquery that tests for the row's existence (so as not to insert duplicates), setting `c_index` to 0. Then `update` the row with `set c_index =c_index +1`.

```
create procedure tablename_add @code int
as
-- add the row if it's not already there
insert tablename values (@code, 0)
where code not in 
      (select code from tablename where code = @code)
-- increase the count by one
update tablename set c_index = c_index + 1
where code = @code
```

You don't even need to define a transaction.  If there's no row, the `INSERT` will succeed and set `c_index` to zero, otherwise it will have no effect.  Then the update will increment `c_index1`, regardless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. I didn't get your idea. Can you explain more, please?

Comment: I added the SQL you'd need to my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get you data set up in the database before inserting the new value, execute this:

```
UPDATE trial tr
   SET c_index = (SELECT MAX(c_index) + 1
                  FROM trial
                 WHERE code = tr.code);

COMMIT;
```

After that, here's atrigger which will update the value correspondingly (the newly inserted ones):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_update
AFTER INSERT ON trial
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
v_index NUMBER := -1; -- "-1" is put in place so to be below the minimum value of the column v_cnt NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

  SELECT MAX(c_index), COUNT(*)
    INTO v_index, v_cnt
    FROM trial
   WHERE code = :new.code;

  IF v_index <> -1 AND v_cnt > 1 THEN
  --Only one update here, for the newly inserted row explicitly
    UPDATE trial
       SET c_index = c_index +1
     WHERE code    = :new.code
       AND c_index = v_index
       AND ROWNUM  = 1;

  END IF;
END;
```

I edited the trigger, it works well on my side, but note it will work correctly after the first update query. If the problem with the DECLARE persistes, then try removing it for instance, sometimes it's not amndatory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. 

I ran the code above, but it didn't compile correctly; those are the errors that appeared to me:
1- Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" 
2- Error(7,8): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'V_INDEX'
3- Error(9,15): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CODE'

However, I will post the new code after correcting two of the errors which are 2 and 3. I couldn't fix the first one because I couldn't understand the error itself.

Comment: There were two DECLAREs in the code, I apologize for that. Unfortunately where I work I can't create those tables and test the query and the trigger I pasted here.

Comment: Hi, Even after keeping one decleare for both variables, the same error appears!!! I'm still trying to search for solutions to figure out how to solve it. Any ways, Thank you very much. Still looking for someone to help me. I need to finish this trigger as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok let me try to re-work it, in the given conditions and I'll see what I can do then and edit my comment.

Comment: I tried your code again. It compiled with no errors, which is good, very good. I went directly to test the insertion, but it does give me an error: SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger

Comment: This is how I do the insertion: insert into trial (code)
values (1111);

Comment: These are the errors that I have after inserting new value: SQL Error: ORA-04091: table TRIAL1 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TRG_UPDATE", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TRG_UPDATE'

Comment: I descovered another problem with the first update code: 

SET INDEX = (SELECT MAX(c_index) + 1
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column

I searched for a solution then I changed it to be:

SET tr.c_index = (SELECT MAX(c_index) + 1

Is this what cause the problem for me when I do the insertion?

Comment: Yes, that was it, I spelled wrongly the c_index field with only "index".

Comment: Hi,
I corrected the mistake, the trigger was compiled, but when I insert a new value I see this message:
ORA-04091: table TRIAL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

As I understood from the internet after searching: selecting and updating from the same table is the reason of that message.

Still trying to figure out the solution. 

Thank you g00dy.

Ali